# Setting focus to a textbox within an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, focus, updatepanel

I have four textboxes within an UpdatePanel, and AutoPostBack is set to True for all of them.  When the user enters a value and hits Enter, I want the cursor to move to the next textbox automatically.  When I don't have the controls in an UpdatePanel, the standard textbox.focus method works fine.

I found some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855047/set-always-focus-on-textbox-asp-net-updatepanel) that led me to create this:

```
    Protected Sub txtField_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtField1.TextChanged,
    txtField2.TextChanged, txtField3.TextChanged
    'Based on the textbox where data was changed, move the cursor to the next field.

    Try
        Dim sm As ScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me)

        'As multiple textboxes fire this same event, determine which textbox triggered this.
        Dim MyTextbox As TextBox = TryCast(sender, TextBox)

        Select Case MyTextbox.ID.ToString
            Case "txtField1"
                sm.SetFocus(txtField2)
            Case "txtField2"
                sm.SetFocus(txtField3)
            Case "txtField3"
                sm.SetFocus(txtField4)
        End Select

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblError.Text = "Error in [txtField_TextChanged]: " & ex.Message
    End Try

End Sub
```

What is really strange is that this works **ONCE** on whatever field I try first.  After that, the event is fired, but the focus does not change.  Is there something additional I need to to for subsequent calls?

I would appreciate any suggestions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `EnablePartialRendering` property of the `ScriptManager` to `false`, like so:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

I hope this helps! Good luck, and happy coding :)